# How can I solve Attribute Error for Rendering using Python?

Tags: python, glsl, rendering, renderer

class MyRenderer(Renderer):

```
def __init__(self, svbrdf, mesh, camera, size):
    super().__init__(size, 0, 500, camera, show=True)

    self.renderables = [Renderable(material, {
        'a_position': vertex_positions,
        'a_normal': vertex_normals,
        'a_tangent': vertex_tangents,
        'a_bitangent': vertex_bitangents,
        'a_uv': vertex_uvs,
        }, len(self.lights))]

def update_uniforms(self):
    self.program['cam_pos'] = linalg.inv(self.camera.view_mat())[:3, 3]
    self.program['u_view_mat'] = self.camera.view_mat().T
    self.program['u_model_mat'] = np.eye(4)
    self.program['u_perspective_mat'] = self.camera.perspective_mat().T

    for i, light in enumerate(self.lights):
        self.program['light_position[{}]'.format(i)] = light.position
        self.program['light_intensity[{}]'.format(i)] = light.intensity
        self.program['light_color[{}]'.format(i)] = light.color

def draw(self):
    gloo.clear(color=(1, 1, 1))
    for renderable in self.renderables:
        self.program = renderable.program
        self.update_uniforms()
        self.program.draw(gl.GL_TRIANGLES)
```

That code has AttributeError
('MyRenderer' object has no attribute renderables)

How to solve? please help me.

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what's going on from the code fragments. Is the setting for `self.renderables` in the` __init__` method? Or somewhere else? Is it possible that wherever it is set is not being called before the `draw` or `on_key_press` methods?

Comment: self.renderatbles is in the  def '__init__'.

Comment: Just to double-check: is the method called `init` or `__init__` (init with two underscores on each side)? In a Python class, the constructor is called `__init__`, which can be confusing at first.

Comment: There are full code. I already call the "＿＿init＿＿" in class.

Comment: I suppose you got the error not in the code you have provided in the question. This is a class definition - how do you use it? You also did not provide the full traceback so it is unknown where the error actually occures. As a result there is no enough information about the problem for now. Add these details please.

Comment: This is very puzzling. To figure it out, I would try to simplify your code as much as possible to focus on the way you initialize and reference `renderables`, perhaps using a different attribute name just to keep it separate, and make sure you are setting up the class correctly, and then creating the instance and invoking the methods correctly. Sometimes it's necessary to go through it very carefully to spot the problem.